# skip take methods with javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

Are there methods by which I can skip a particular number of objects and take a certain number of objects from an array in javascript?

Basically the pattern I'm looking for is this.

Say I have an array of 8 objects.

**First loop:**

Return objects at index 0 to 3 from the array.

**Second loop:**

return objects at index 4 to 7 from the array.

**Third loop**:

Back to the beginning so return objects at 0 to 3 again.

Ad infinitum.....

I'd love to see a jquery based solution if possible but I'm all open for raw javascript implementations too as I'm eager to learn.

Cheers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Something like this (plain JavaScript, no need for jQuery ;)):

```
var iterator = function(a, n) {
    var current = 0,
        l = a.length;
    return function() {
        end = current + n;
        var part = a.slice(current,end);
        current =  end < l ? end : 0;
        return part;
    };
};
```

Then you can call it:

```
var next = iterator(arr, 3);
next(); // gives the first three
next(); // gives the next three.
//etc.
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/k6GGC/)

It this form, the last iteration might return less elements. You could also extend it and make the function accept a variable step and a different start parameter.

If you want to wrap around, like if there are only two elements left, to take elements from the beginning, then it gets a bit more sophisticated ;)

**Update:** Wrap around would be something like this:

```
var iterator = function(a, n) {
    var current = 0,
        l = a.length;
    return function() {
        end = current + n;
        var part = a.slice(current,end);
        if(end > l) {
            end = end % l;
            part = part.concat(a.slice(0, end));
        }
        current = end;
        return part;
    };
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/k6GGC/3/)

Comment: @FelixKling: +1 for clean solution and for reminding me of the old [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/) days.

Comment: @ Felix: Quite frankly... wow! No wonder you've got such a healthy rep! I think I get what's going on.... Would calling next() each time ensure that I will go back to the beginning of the array once I had reached the end? Further to your update... take from the start again... Yes please!!

Comment: @JamesSouth: Yes it would work, but I had a slight error in the code. Fixed it.... give me some seconds for the other thing ;)

Comment: @Felix: Wizard... Looking forward to seeing it!

Comment: @JamesSouth: Updated my code. See the demo. Works for me so far ;)

Comment: @Felix: You sir...are a genius! Fantastic stuff... I love this site and I love the heroes who make it work so well.

Comment: the solution using slice seems easier

Answer (score 28):

I think you want [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) or [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

```
var ary = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
alert(ary.splice(0,3).join(','));
```

Comment: Be warned that splice will remove elements from your original array. Slice will not.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at this. array.slice()

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

Comment: Obligatory "Eww, w3fools". (I don't really care, but thought I'd mention it before the next guy and be a tad less derogatory)

Comment: @Brad ok.. so why should I not use the site?  It has the answer (with a ton of ads I suppose.)

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm really indifferent, but there are some people that are [really passionate](http://w3fools.com/) about not using it.

Comment: In general,  MDC (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript) is a much better source.

Comment: slice(indexStart, indexEnd) returns the page array... the indexEnd parameter is not inclusive

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with JavaScript ***[generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator)***. Here is an example:

```js
function* jumpAndSliceGenerator(arr, n) {
    let start = 0;
    while(start + n < arr.length) {
        const end = start + n;
        const part = arr.slice(start, end);
        start =  end;
        yield part;
    }
    yield arr.slice(start);
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
for (const arrPart of jumpAndSliceGenerator(arr, 3)) {
  console.log(arrPart);
}
```

> If the array is not divisible by jump size, then the last slice will have all the rest elements which are less than jump size

Answer (score 1):

If you have a jQuery reference, jQuery has a [slice method too](http://api.jquery.com/slice).